# Yarn fails when yarn install twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, continuous-integration, docker-compose, yarnpkg

When I run yarn + rails in a docker container I cannot execute yarn twice during my Jenkins build process. Does anyone of you know a good solution for the usage of yarn in a Jenkins pipeline.

I currently create a docker-compose file and execute my commands on the container with rails + yarn installed. The first yarn install command is always passing but further yarn installs keep failing which are automatically used by rails to check integrity.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cache or test it with npm -g